# User input only ever returns one "if" value, but not the other

Tags: javascript, input, calculator

I'm creating an input field to have students enter the number of questions they got wrong, and the program will return the number they got correct. This example is for a 10 question test. When I enter the number "1" into the input, I get "9" returned (which is correct). But when I enter the number "0" into the input, I also get "9" returned, but I'm expecting to get "10". What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your responses.

```
<p>Enter the Number Incorrect</p>
<br />

<input type="number" id="myscore" />
<button onclick="myJsFunction()"><p>Submit</p></button>
<script>
    function myJsFunction() {
    var numberwrong = document.getElementById('myscore').value;
    if (numberwrong = 0) {
        score = "10";
    }
    else if (numberwrong = 1) {
        score = "9";
    }
    document.getElementById("totalscore").innerHTML = score;
}
</script>

<p id="totalscore"></p>
```

Comment: should be comparison operator `==` not assignment `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re not using comparison operators correctly try using double equals `==` instead of single `=`.

```
function myJsFunction() {
var numberwrong = document.getElementById('myscore').value;
if (numberwrong == 0) {
    score = "10";
}
else if (numberwrong == 1) {
    score = "9";
}
document.getElementById("totalscore").innerHTML = score;
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you.

Comment: I aim to please. You could mark my answer as the correct one if you feel so inclined ;)

Comment: I tried but it made me wait 10 minutes to mark it as correct :) Will do though.